# How to connect to a SSL encrypted OData Feed

Tags: c#, ssl, uwp, odata

I try to add a connected Service in Visual Studio (UWP-App) to read from my Odata feed. The problem is that the odata service is SSL encrypted and visual studio tells me that he cannot access the feed for some reason.

[image: here is the error message]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now it doesn't seem to be possible to connect to a SSL-encrypted OData-feed in an UWP-App.

So i created my own WCF-Service, which I host on an IIS, to gather my informations directly from an SQL-server

Here are some useful link collections about  creating a WCF Service, hosting that on an IIS and a UWP sample project:

1. [How to build a WCF](https://youtu.be/GQsLaLOAKIk)
2. [host WCF on IIS](https://youtu.be/g-w1GvkwErk)
3. [UWP sample project](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-access-data-from-5f2602ec#content)